# Is it possible to do Cassandra query from usergrid api

Tags: cassandra, apigee, usergrid

I'm using usergrid and need to execute raw Cassandra query. Is it possible to execute raw Cassandra query from usergrid api?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible through the API.

Comment: Is there any hack to execute raw query? If no then, what would be the best alternative to solve problem that require raw query execution.

Comment: @Pattinson You'd have to fork the Usergrid project and write that interface yourself.

Comment: No, that's completely unsupported functionality - you're pretty much on your own ;)

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible.

Use like this.

$query_string = array('access_token'=>$oauth_token,'limit'=>'10'); // Use more condition here.
$users = $client->get_collection('users',$query_string);

Comment: This will do the query over elasticsearch, not cassandra.